# Как решить проблему с методом super() в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы, конструктор

Почему возникает ошибка?

```
class Tree():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.height = 0
        self.age = 0
        self.name = name

    def info(self):
        print(f'Name: {self.name}\nHeight: {self.height}\nAge: {self.age}\n')

    def grow(self):
        self.age += 1
        self.height = 2 ** self.age


tree = Tree('oak')

tree.info()

tree.grow()
tree.info()

class FruitTree(Tree):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(age)

    def get_fruit(self):
        print(f'Apples: {self.Tree.age/2}')

fruit = FruitTree()

fruit.get_fruit()
```

---

Ошибка в 24 строке:

> `super().__init__(age)`
>
> NameError: name '`age`' is not defined

В чем проблема?

Comment: Проблема в том, что "'age' is not defined" для class FruitTree(Tree)  :-)

Comment: это понятно, но как ее решить?

Comment: Логикой - как в super попадет age? Или посмотреть синтаксис конструктора в описании super в документации. У вас там кроме self, ничего нет. Как минимум, надо `def __init__(self, age):`

Comment: И кстати у вас у Tree init принимает один параметр name. А вы пытаетесь передать этим параметром age из FruitTree. Т.е. если вы даже добавите параметр age в init FruitTree вы уверены, что хотите передать его в качестве параметра name в Tree ?

Comment: А потом у вас всплывет ошибка в get_fruit вы там обращаетесь к self.Tree.age, а в self у вас никакого Tree нет, у вас есть просто self.age так как он объявлен в родительском классе

Comment: Как перенести именно атрибут, из одного класса в другой, чтобы использовать его в другом классе?

Comment: Атрибуты наследуются. так что после того как вы вызовете просто `super().__init__('имя')` из `__init__` FruitTree вы уже сможете обращаться к тому age, что объявлен в Tree из FruitTree как к собственному т.е. просто self.age

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не уверен что правильно понял вас, но предложу попробовать так:

```
class Tree():
    def __init__(self, name=''):                                                     # +++ name=''
        super().__init__()    
        self.height = 0
        self.age = 0
        self.name = name

    def info(self):
        print(f'Tree() - Name: {self.name}; Height: {self.height}; Age: {self.age}')

    def grow(self):
        self.age += 1
        self.height = 2 ** self.age
        print(f'Tree() - Name: {self.name}; Height: {self.height}; Age: {self.age}') # +++


class FruitTree(Tree):
    def __init__(self):
#        super().__init__(age)
        super().__init__()                                                           # +++
        
        print(f'\nFruitTree(Tree): self.age = {self.age}; tree.age = {tree.age}')    # +++ 

    def get_fruit(self):
#        print(f'Apples: {self.Tree.age/2}')
        print(f'Apples: {tree.age / 2}\n')                                           # +++ tree.age
        

tree = Tree('oak')
tree.info()
tree.grow()
tree.info()        

fruit = FruitTree()
fruit.get_fruit()

tree.grow()                   # +++
tree.grow()                   # +++
fruit.get_fruit()             # +++
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

`super().__init__(age)` это, можно сказать, аналог записи  `Tree.__init__(age)`. `age` которая передается в дочернем классе `FruitTree` это **необъявленная переменная** в данном классе. `age` - переменная в классе `FruitTree` и `self.age` в классе `Tree`, это разные переменные. Интерпретатор выдает ошибку.

Также у вас логическая ошибка возникает:

```
class Tree():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.height = 0
        self.age = 0
        self.name = name
```

Конструктор класса `Тree` принимает один параметр - `name`
Который потом присваивается переменной `self.name = name` , соответственно передавая например `age` вот так:

```
class FruitTree(Tree):
    def __init__(self):
        age = 12
        super().__init__(age)
```

В родительском классе будет происходить следующее:

```
 class Tree():
     def __init__(self, name):
         self.height = 0
         self.age = 0
         # переменная name = 12
         self.name = name
         # self.name = 12
```